# Click an Onclick Event in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying click a menu icon which has the following html code

```
<a href="#" class="ctm-icon-link" onclick="show_menu('doc_107094', 1); return false;"><i class="icon-left-space icon-chevron-sign-down">&nbsp;</i></a>
```

doc_number -Number will change each time 
My code to click the icon menu

```
FindElement(By.ClassName("ctm-icon-link"));
FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='#']@onclick"));
FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href="#"]@class"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with respect to the `onclick` *event* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *XPath* 1:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[@class='ctm-icon-link' and starts-with(@onclick, 'show_menu')]")));
  ```
- *XPath* 2:

  ```
  IWebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//a[@class='ctm-icon-link' and starts-with(@onclick, 'show_menu')]/i")));
  ```

Comment: Where is the said _WebDriverWait_ in your solution?

Comment: @Jonah That was my bad, thanks for pointing out, updated the answer